# Como pegar os nomes de todas as tabelas de database PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, tabela-banco-de-dados

Como pegar os nomes de todas as tabelas de database PostgreSQL?

Como pegar os atributos(codigo, nome, etc...) de uma determinada tabela no banco de dados PostgreSQL?

Comment: Você está utilizando o psql ou sua intenção é usar essas informações em uma query só?

Comment: @CamiloSantos Uma query só

Comment: Ok... então a resposta do Igor deve resolver teu problema :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para obter o nome de todas as tabelas, use o comando abaixo:

```
SELECT table_name 
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema='public'
AND table_type='BASE TABLE';
```

Para obter os atributos de uma tabela, use o comando abaixo:

```
SELECT column_name, data_type, character_maximum_length
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE table_name = '<NOME DA TABELA>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma das alternativas é utilizar os catálogos do postgres. As tabelas de catálogo possuem um formato mais adequado ao postgres como tipos específicos do SGDB e possibilidade de uso de algumas funções.

```
select
  relnamespace::regnamespace as schema,
  relname as tabela,
  attname as coluna,
  format_type(atttypid,atttypmod) as tipo
from pg_class c
  inner join pg_attribute a
    on (c.oid=a.attrelid)
where attnum>0
  and relnamespace='public'::regnamespace --usar se necessário filtrar um schema
  and relname in ('clientes','tributacao'); --usar se necessário filtrar por tabela
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-class.html
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-attribute.html
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html